# Windows 7 File Explorer doesn't shows folders but notepad does

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-explorer

I am using Windows 10 and Windows 7 dual-boot and today Windows 7's file explorer stopped showing folders on any directory, but it shows files (system files too if I deselect "Hide protected system files..."). Windows 10 still shows these folders but Windows 7 doesn't. But when I click "Save as" in Notepad or any other software, it shows folders.

Here are the images:

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I only have Win10 now, but I remember from XP that occasionally the [FFlags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-folderflags) value for savied folder views would somehow pick up the `FWF_SINGLESEL` flag, preventing multiple file selections.

This sounds like they've picked up the `FWF_NOSUBFOLDERS` flag.

The thing I'm not sure of is the exact registry location for Win 7. Under `XP`, the key was:
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags`

Under `Win 10`, the views are saved under:
`HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`

If you're comfortable with **PowerShell**, you can test with the following:

```
$RegPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'

# OR depending on what path your found in your registry

$RegPath = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags'

# THEN

gci $RegPath /s | ? Property -contains 'FFlags' | ForEach{
    If ( ( $FFLags = $_.GEtValue('FFlags')) -band 0x00000080  ) {
        echo 'FWF_NOSUBFOLDERS'
    }
}
```

If it returns to the prompt with no output, thnen this isn't the issue. But if you see `FWF_NOSUBFOLDERS`, it is.

If you not fanatical about saved views, you can open Regedit & Task Manager on am otherwise quiet system, kill the Explorer (Shell) process from Task Manager, then delete the `Bags` key & its sibling, `BagMRU`.

If you find that's issue but want to keep your saved views, I can amend this post with the code to clear the flag.

Comment: When I entered the command to PowerShell, it not gived any output. I stopped explorer, deleted Bags key in registry and restarted explorer but nothing changed expect size of explorer window. Any other solutions?

Comment: **View** on ribbon (Alt+V), **Options**,  **Change Folder and Search Options**, **View** tab, **Reset Folders**.

Comment: See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/vista-folder-content-different-then-same-folder/39487ef8-602f-4e68-b3cc-b5c2152a9e5c for how it worked in Win Vista.